# else clause to repeat ajax triggers too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, cgi

I have an ajax function on my website which calls a cgi script. infrequently, this script returns a 500 error. I am trying to change the AJAX call so that when this happens, it will repeat the request. I have tried to do that as follows:

```
function shelverx() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //process data if successful...
        } else if (xmlhttp.status == 500) {
            limit++;
            if (limit < 5) {
                shelverx(usershelf);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", filepath, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(postdata);
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this? I find that what happens is that whenever there is a 500 error, the shelverx function is called four times, even if the second call is successful. Is there a way to repeat the call only once per error?

I also tried to accomplish the same thing by changing the entire ajax call to jQuery and using the following error function:

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
           this.tryCount++;
           if (this.tryCount<=this.retryLimit) {
               $.ajax(this);
           return;
           }
```

But I got an `Unexpected Token :` error. If anyone could help me to get either of these methods to work I would appreciate it greatly. My goal is to have the ajax call repeat only once per 500 error.

Comment: where is `limit` variable defined? this is your problem for stack overflow ;), presumably it is being redefined each time back to zero and does not maintain or update based on its previous values

Comment: seems like a bandage over  the main issue...whatever causes the 500 and why errors aren't caught in the server side script.

Comment: As Nikos suggested, the problem is most likely caused by volatile variables. Turn on the debugger and place a break point at the IF statement.

Comment: limit is a global variable - it isn't being reset - that's the reason that the ajax call is only being made four times.

Comment: I apologize - I see why there was confusion - I'm not getting a stack overflow error - I edited the title of my question to better reflect the actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonathan -

The code snippet below works as you want. The counter holds its value between calls and stops requests at 5. I also changed the IF statement logic and added a timer to wait 1 second between tries. Give it a try.

Note that the original logic doesn't work correctly. In the debugger it was incrementing the counter multiple times per each request. Much better to check status after readyState = 4.

**Original Code:**

```
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //process data if successful...
    } else if (xmlhttp.status == 500) {
        limit++;
        if (limit < 5) {
            shelverx(usershelf);
        }
    }
```

**Tested and working example:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var postdata = '';
        var filepath = 'NothingHere.html';
        var limit = 0;

        function shelverx() {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        console.info('Success: Recieved ' + xmlhttp.responseText.length + ' bytes');
                    } 
                    else {
                        limit++;
                        console.info( 'Error: ' + xmlhttp.status + ':' + xmlhttp.statusText );
                        if (limit < 5) setTimeout( shelverx, 1000 );
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", filepath, true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(postdata);
        }

        shelverx();
      
</script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was silly of me not to think of separating the readystate and status - that did the trick. I understand now what was happening - when the status was not 200 the else statement would trigger once for each change of state.